# how to change debuginfo-install repository

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

```
[root@new-host ~]# gdb -q hello1
Reading symbols from /root/hello1...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/hello1 

Program exited with code 0244.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
(gdb)
```

I want to install debuginfo on my CentOS 6.4 system.

But I can not install that...

```
[root@new-host ~]# debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.i686
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

How can I find the appropriate repo for my system?

How can I add the repository url to the debuginfo-install tool?

:(

Answer (score 6):

- For a quick fix, you can just grab [http://debuginfo.centos.org/6/i386/glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.107.el6.i686.rpm](http://glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.107.el6.i686.rpm) and pass it to `rpm -i`.
- A proper fix would involve a bit of troubleshooting as to why you're current repo configuration can't find the package. Look into `/etc/yum.repos.d/` if grepping for "debug" shows the repo configuration is using a `mirrorlist` instead of a `baseurl` then it's likely because the mirror you get is outdated. You might want to then point the `centos-debuginfo` or `updates-debuginfo` repo to **debuginfo.centos.org** through a `baseurl` entry.